# Hot water flowing into an upside down glass

Tags: thermodynamics

Hot water from a glass is poured onto a flat plate and the glass is then quickly inverted onto the plate. Why does the water slowly flow into the glass? (I know it has something to do with the gas laws and/or thermodynamics)

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the [Ideal Gas Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law).

This says there is a relationship in gasses between pressure, temperature and volume (in a fixed mass).  The main conclusion is that $$PV \ \alpha \ T$$ where $P$ is pressure, $V$ is volume, $T$ is temperature (and $\alpha$ means "is proportional to") for an ideal gas (air usually behaves fairly ideally).

By keeping the glass sealed by water and the plate, you are fixing variables.  The temperature will decrease as the hot air cools down in the glass.  There becomes a problem, the pressure and/or volume of the air trapped in the glass will need to decrease due to the ideal gas law.

What happens is that the pressure will decrease in the glass, this will cause the water in the plate to move upwards until the pressure and volume have balanced to accommodate the pressure difference. You can think of it as momentarily lowering the pressure in the glass, but atmospheric pressure pushes the water up the glass a bit, similar to how old [barometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer) worked.  This will decrease the volume so that the ideal gas law will still hold.

Comment: That V does not represent velocity.

Comment: Hahahaha good catch wow.  I was on autopilot.